# My logo in the header nav won't appear for some reason?

Tags: html, css, file, header, navbar

HTML :

```css
.logo {
  width: 150px;
  height: auto;
  float: left;
  margin: 20px;
  background: url('logo.png');
}
```

```html
<header></header>
<body>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="logo">
      <img src="logo.png" alt="check">
    </div>
    <ul class="main-nav">
      <ul>
        <li class="active"><a href="index.html">HOME</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">ABOUT</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">CONTACT</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">BLOG</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">SERVICE</a></li>
        <li><a href="blog.html">STUDY</a></li>
      </ul>
    </ul>
  </div>
  </body>
```

I tried doing this but for some reason it doesn't show.
It works with *url EXP: src="http//..."*  but when I put it from my images it cant find it how can i make it work?

I put my image on OneDrive in a folder called sublime and then I put the logo in that folder. I use windows 10. 
For some reason the image is cropped. I would expect the whole image to be shown and not just a portion of it

Comment: It sounds like the file path to your `logo.png` is incorrect

Comment: Are you able to take a screenshot of your projects file structure so we can check if the filepath is correct

Comment: can u plz share the folder structure? I think the image path is wrong!!

Comment: what is error in console?

Comment: Make sure your path to image is correct.